What's the difference between FourierSinCoefficient and FourierSinSeries in in terms of results?
Let's assume having defined a sawtooth:
saw[t_] := 2*(SawtoothWave[t + 0.5] - 0.5)

Now, we'd like to compute sine fourier coefficients for that sawtooth. We may do this for specific coeffients (e.g. first order):
sinCoeff1 = FourierSinCoefficient[saw[t],t,1,FourierParameters->{0,-2\[Pi]}]

Result: -0.31831
An alternate way for the first and second order coefficients:
g[t_] = FullSimplify[
  FourierSinSeries[saw[t], t, 2, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 \[Pi]}]]

Result: 0.63662 Sin[2 \[Pi] t] - 0.31831 Sin[4 \[Pi] t]
So there are different results for the first order coefficient (inverted and half).
I've read a post covering the same issue for the cosine series: Inconsistency between FourierTrigSeries and FourierCosCoefficient.
The explanation given in the post makes sense. So I took to the Wolfam Documentation for FouriersSinCoefficient and FourierSinSeries.
FourierSinSeries coefficient is defined as
.
FourierSinCoefficient is defined as

I haven't found a definition of the sine series per se (only for the coefficients). What am I missing?
Thanks for helping me out.

Your words do not correspond to reality. In the case of parameters [a,b] FourierSinCoefficient is defined as RealAbs[2b/Pi]^((a+1)/2)*Integrate[f[t]*Sin[b*n*t],{t,0,Pi/RealAbs[b]}].

Would you have a reference for me?

It is probably a bug in FourierSinCoefficient.

Could be. FourierTrigSeries looks ok.

I'm running 14.0.0.0 on Win x64.

You incorrectly understand documentation. See Details and Options in FourierSinCoefficient and pay your attention to the multiplier RealAba[2b/Pi]^((1-a)/2) before  the series.

Please look up the documentation for both: FourierSinSeries and FourierSinCoefficient. Both give the quoted multiplier. Per documentation it is the same for the (single) coefficient and the coefficients computed by the "series" command. So the result ought to be the same.

@user64494 The point is that the information about any multiplier is missing in the documentation of FourierSinCoefficient. You can read about the multiplier only in the documentation of FourierSinSeries. Your link in the comment is misleading,  it pretends it is link to FourierSinCoefficient but in fact it is link to FourierSinSeries.

@azerbajdzan: There is a link to the documentation to FourireSeries in the question with title "What's the difference between FourierSinCoefficient and FourierSinSeries in in terms of results?".

@azerbajdzan: I think that multipler should be included in FourierSinCoefficient .

I think the formulas in the documentation are not correct I made some adjustments to the formula and now the FourierSinSeries coincides with FourierSinCoefficient.
So probably not a bug in FourierSinCoefficient but bug in the documentation of FourierSinCoefficient.
a = 0; b = -2 π;
saw[t_] := 2*(SawtoothWave[t + 0.5] - 0.5)

Table[-Abs[(2 b)/π]^((1 - a)/2) Sin[2 n π t] 
    FourierSinCoefficient[saw[t], 
    t, n, FourierParameters -> {a, b}], {n, 0, 10}] // Total

FourierSinSeries[saw[t], t, 10, 
  FourierParameters -> {a, b}] == %

Plot[{saw[t], %%}, {t, 0, 2 π}]

Clear[a, b]


0.63662 Sin[2 π t] - 0.31831 Sin[4 π t] + 
 0.212207 Sin[6 π t] - 0.159155 Sin[8 π t] + 
 0.127324 Sin[10 π t] - 0.106103 Sin[12 π t] + 
 0.0909457 Sin[14 π t] - 0.0795775 Sin[16 π t] + 
 0.0707355 Sin[18 π t] - 0.063662 Sin[20 π t]

True



Your formulas -Abs[(2 b)/π]^((1 - a)/2) Sin[2 n π t]  are from Details and Options in the documentation. Also Table[-Abs[(2  b)/\[Pi]]^((1 - a)/2)  Sin[    2  n  \[Pi]  t]  FourierSinCoefficient[saw[t], t, n,     FourierParameters -> {a, b}], {n, 0, 3}] results in {0, 0.63662 Sin[2 \[Pi] t], -0.31831 Sin[4 \[Pi] t],   0.212207 Sin[6 \[Pi] t]}.

The OP wrongly understands the documentation, not paying his/her attention to the  multiplier RealAba[2b/Pi]^((1-a)/2) before the series in Details and Options in the documentation to FourierSinCoefficient.

Again, would you (user64494) please provide references?

@azerbajdzan: Thanks. Problem addressed.

Sorry, it should be "in Details and Options in the documentation to FourierSeries" instead of "in Details and Options in the documentation to FourierSinCoefficient" in my comment.

Additional clarification from the Mathematica support team: The default coefficients for the single coefficient and the series are different. As of today, this is not documented.
